# Migrate data of Bae64Encode CSV file to SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to get help on solving an issue. Kindly please help.

I have a Base64 encoded `.CSV` file that I downloaded using SSIS from an endpoint URL. That file has 4 columns and 1 column row which I matter is File column with base64 encoded value. I was able to dump that column into SQL Server table using SSIS, then I used this code to decode using T-SQL:

```
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),
        CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("FILE"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)')) AS RESULT    
    FROM ABC
```

The result from the query above looks like this:

```
Agentid,agentname, phone, email, address,state,country, zip,ssn 1,nick,56677700987,abc@yahoo.com,address,tx,12345,9990009999 2,Jack,12677700987,abcuu@yahoo.com,address,tx,145,12990009999 3,mike,56677700987,abcd@yahoo.com,address,tx,12345,9990009999
```

The desired result should look like this:

```
+---------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+----------+-------+---------+-------------+-----+
| Agentid | agentname |    phone    |      email      |  address | state | country |     zip     | ssn |
+---------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+----------+-------+---------+-------------+-----+
|       1 | nick      | 56677700987 | abc@yahoo.com   | address  | tx    |   12345 |  9990009999 |     |
|       2 | Jack      | 12677700987 | abcuu@yahoo.com | address  | tx    |     145 | 12990009999 |     |
|       3 | mike      | 56677700987 | abcd@yahoo.com  | address  | tx    |   12345 |  9990009999 |     |
+---------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+----------+-------+---------+-------------+-----+
```

Comment: the o/p of the above convert
is I have CSV data which looks like
Agentid,agentname, phone, email, address,state,country, zip,ssn 1,nick,56677700987,abc@yahoo.com,address,tx,12345,9990009999 2,Jack,12677700987,abcuu@yahoo.com,address,tx,145,12990009999 3,mike,56677700987,abcd@yahoo.com,address,tx,12345,9990009999,

Comment: something like that as 1 ROW .
but when I copy and paste in csv or ssms I see as formated csv data 
Agentid,agentname, phone, email, address,state,country, zip,ssn
1,nick,56677700987,abc@yahoo.com,address,tx,12345,9990009999
2,Jack,12677700987,abcuu@yahoo.com,address,tx,145,12990009999
3,mike,56677700987,abcd@yahoo.com,address,tx,12345,9990009999
now, what I would like to do is take /convert do some t SQL magic with function and insert this same row into a new readable table( as 1 row as column and then all as rows)

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: ok, Thanks ..I'm new to the posting/asking questions.sorry